# Attempting to use aggregate $geoNear with Mongoose but receiving error: "Near field must be point"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, geojson

I'm building an API using Express and Mongoose. I have a Reviews collection that has a location field which stores geoJSON. I'm attempting to query my Reviews collection using **aggregate** and **$geoNear**.

Here's the relevant portion from my ReviewSchema:

```
location: { 
    type: { 
      type: String, 
      default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: { 
      type: [Number] 
    } 
  }
```

I also added a **2dsphere** index:

```
ReviewSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
```

I'm able to successfully query the collection using **find** and **$nearSphere**:

```
router.get('/:longitude/:latitude/:dist', (req, res) => {
  Review.find({
    location: {
     $nearSphere: {
       $geometry: {
         type: 'Point',
         coordinates: [req.params.longitude, req.params.latitude]
       },
       $maxDistance: req.params.dist * 1609.34
     }
   }
  })
  .then(reviews => res.json(reviews))
});
```

When attempting to use aggregate and $geoNear however I get an error:

> near field must be point

Here's the route with the query:

```
router.get('/:longitude/:latitude', (req, res) => {
  Review.aggregate([{
     $geoNear: {
       near: {
         type: "Point",
         coordinates: [req.params.longitude, req.params.latitude]
       },
       spherical: true,
       maxDistance: 10 * 1609,
       distanceField: 'distance'
     }
   }])
   .then(reviews => res.json(reviews))
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

The syntax for my query is based off the MongoDB documentation for $geoNear. Am I using this incorrectly with Mongoose?

Comment: Try this `parseFloat(req.params.longitude)` and similarly for latitude.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Thank you Anthony! This solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the coordinates which are always should be numeric whereas you put it as `String`

So instead convert them to integer or float value

```
Review.aggregate([{
  "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [parseFloat(req.params.longitude), parseFloat(req.params.latitude)]
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "maxDistance": 10 * 1609,
    "distanceField": "distance"
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to add to this one - the geocoords must also be valid, and the query is lng,lat - if you get them backwards or simply specify an invalid co-ordinate then you get the same error.